# Changing keyboard layouts in Xubuntu with certain keyboard combination

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xubuntu

I've recently moved from Ubuntu 10.10 to Xubuntu 11.10.

I've found [a script to toggle keyboard layouts](http://ubuntu.sabza.org/2006/10/13/xubuntu-easily-switch-keyboard-layout/) via a certain key combination. You have to specify the combination to toggle the layout yourself.

Why I can't use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> to toggle with this script?

Answer (score 0):

Why indeed? Since your script is not shown, the first hypothesis is that there was a mistake in it.

Consult `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` for a list of possible parameters:

```
grp:shift_caps_toggle Shift+Caps Lock
```